# Fetching values from an object with nested objects

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using a service where I don't know the actual structure of the response. Therefore I'm returning it as an `object`:

```
object result = Service.GetStuff();
```

If I inspect it in the debugger, it looks something like this:

[image]

I've tried casting it to `dynamic`, `Hashtable` and `Arraylist`, without success. How do I access the properties on the object? Similar SO questions haven't helped me.

> *Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type `object'*

Comment: How about trying foreach() loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the result is *always* an array (or something that implements `IList`, like an `ArrayList`), you can cast it to an `IList`, which is where the index operator is defined:

```
IList result = Service.GetStuff() as IList;
```

Then you can apply the index operator.  If it's not always an array then you could use reflection to determine if it *is* an array, then cast it.

The bigger question is, what are you going to *do* with the objects since you don't know what they are?

Comment: Casting to `IList` results in `null` for some reason. I know what the objects are, so I guess that creating classes that represents the objects is my second option?

Comment: What is the underlying type?

Comment: `IEnumerable` does not support indexed access.

Comment: `Dictionary<string, object>` combined with lambda did the trick. `FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Key == "dataVersion")`. Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it is some sort of dictionary try casting the object to `IDictionary`. If that does not help, you may call the `result.GetType()` to see what is the actual type and cast to that.

I also think that dynamic should work too.

```
dynamic result = Service.GetStuff();
int reconnectDelay = ((dynamic)result[0]).reconnectDelay;
```